# Trying to understand Replication/Consitency Factors

Tags: cassandra, replication, datastax-java-driver, consistency

(cassandra noob) 
I have been doing some basic config/perf tests to and try an get a better understanding of how cassandra works, and was a bit suprised at the results.

My tests essentially do: (multi-threaded (each thread simply doing an insert), 50k messages total).

Test 1: Single-Node Only (no cluster) Insert with Consistency=1. (note: test is run on this host, pointing to the local cassandra)

Result: tps=5000tps.

For Test 2,3 we using 4 Datacenters, (1 node in each), where the table is configured USING REPLICATION = 4

** Tests 2/3 (the client is again running directly on one of the nodes with Cassandra installed and is pointing directly at that localhost cassandra).

Test 2: Insert with Consistency=1

Result: tps = 423

Test 3: Insert with Consistency=4

Result: tps = 149

Originally I was expecting Test 2 to perform in a similar fashion to Test 1, operating under the assumption that: the insert would block until the insert was written to the commit log of the local cassandra node receiving the request.

Seeing that the performance is vastly slower, I can only conclude that when the insert is received by the local node, it computes a hash and this hash/partition may in fact be hosted by another Cassandra Node as primary?  Even though it will eventually be 'replicated' 'back' to the local node since ConsistencyFactor==Number of nodes in cluster), which is causing the insert to block until a remote node has committed the insert to the commit log.

Is this correct?
If yes..is there a way to 'change' this behavior? i.e. if all nodes in the Cluster have a copy, then when an insert is received with C=1, ensure the receiving node commits it locally, rather then delegating it out?

Note: for my tests I am using the java DataStax 2 driver (could it be this driver, even though when I connecting explicitly to the local node is in fact creating connections to the entire cluster, and dispatching requests to all nodes?)

Thanks
Dano

Comment: Hi dano, can you share your code where you set the consistency levels?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine it was a config issue with the java datastax driver, it was in fact using a RoundRobinPolicy, as such many of the requests with C=1, were being routed to the other datacenters.

When I switched to using LatencyAwarePolicy(DCAwarePolicyRoundRobinPolicy), the numbers are coming in at the expected range.

I am however seeing some odd rpc-timeouts accessing the cluster (from both the java-driver and cqlsh), which am still experimenting with.

Dano